# InDesign: Check if cancel button is clicked on a dialog

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have a script in InDesign which opens a folder dialog.

How can I show an alert if the user pressed the Cancel button and then stop the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two functions that open a File/Folder selection dialog and their behavior is subtly different, but this is the same for both:

> • If the user clicks OK, returns a File object for the selected file, or an array of objects if multiple files are selected.
>   • If the user cancels, returns null.

So where you now have a line such as

```
 myFile = var myFolder.openDlg("Select a file", "*.*", false);
```

you can add this right after:

```
if (myFile == null)
{
    alert ("You pressed Cancel!");
    exit();
}
```

From a user interface point of view, I'd like to add that the `alert` is *probably* not necessary. If a script is said to undertake some action on/with a selected file or folder, pressing "Cancel" in an Open or Save Dialog clearly means the user changed his mind and *wants* it to stop.

Comment: One side note: while this works with predefined dialogs (folder or file open), how do i track the cancel button on custom dialogs in InDesign?

It's a simple dialog with 2 options (create new template or open an existing one) but when I hit cancel it proceeds with an alert saying "Select your files" which means it continues to execute the script.

Comment: What dialog object are you using the InDesign Dialog Object or the ScriptUI framework ?

Comment: I think ScriptUI (sorry not too familiar with InDesign). I'm initializing it as var myDialog = app.dialogs.add({name:"Welcome"});

Comment: It's not ScriptUI but InDesign Dialog Object.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ScriptUI but InDesign Dialog Object.

here is a snippet from the doc…

```js
var myDialog = app.dialogs.add({name:"Simple Dialog"});
//Add a dialog column.
with(myDialog.dialogColumns.add()){
staticTexts.add({staticLabel:"This is a very simple dialog box."});
}
//Show the dialog box.
var myResult = myDialog.show();
//If the user clicked OK, display one message;
//if they clicked Cancel, display a different message.
if(myResult == true){
alert("You clicked the OK button.");
}
else{
alert("You clicked the Cancel button.");
}
//Remove the dialog box from memory.
myDialog.destroy();
```